# How to stop objects being lost between PagedList calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

**Question Background:**

I'm using PagedList MVC to provide paging for a large data set on my View.

**The Issue:**

I have a form on my View which passes an object populated with a users parameters on the form inputs to a method on the controller called `Index`, I also pass the page number the users wishes to navigate too. The first time the form is submitted to the controller method object is populated from the form as expected, when I click on page two I'm passing null properties to the object.

This makes sense as the users is not submitting a form anymore, but I have an issue now where I have lost the orginal filter parameters.

**How can I store the original filtered parameters that popuate the model and send them each time a users changes page?**

**The Code:**

The View with the form and Model:

```
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "ShopComparator", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", OnBegin = "LoadingSpinner", OnSuccess = "MessageSent", OnFailure = "FailedMail" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchValues.searchTerm, new { @class = " form-control", placeHolder = "Item to search for", id = "name" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchValues.searchTerm)

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5 form-group">

                                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SearchValues.searchCatagory, new SelectList(Model.GetCatagories), "Select Product Catagory", new { @class = "form-control" })

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-3 form-group">

                                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SearchValues.countryCode, new SelectList(new List<string> {
                        "UK",
                        "US",
                        "FR",
                        "DE",
                   }), "Select Code", new { @class = "form-control" })


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">

                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Search Prices" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

The Index Method on the HomePage Controller that is called by the above form along with the populated `HomePageVM` object passed from the form along with the page number. **The HomepageVM model has null properties after subsequent page changes from page 1.**

```
    public ActionResult Index(HomePageVM homePageSearch, int pageNo = 1)
    { 
        RootObject response = _httpCaller.CallWebApiEndPoint(homePageSearch.SearchValues.searchTerm, homePageSearch.SearchValues.searchCatagory, homePageSearch.SearchValues.countryCode);

        List<ViewDisplayItem> viewModelResponseList = ConvertToViewModel(response);


        return View(viewModelResponseList.ToPagedList(pageNo, 3));
    }
```

Index View that displays the Items that will be Paged:

```
  @foreach (var item in @Model)
        {
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading textOverflow" id="panelHeading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title text-center"><b>@item.Title</b></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <a href="@item.url"><img src="@item.Image" class="picHeight img-rounded img-responsive center-block" /></a>
                            <h4 class="text-center">@item.Price</h4>
                            <h4 class="text-center"><a href="@item.url" class="btn btn-success">See More</a></h4>
                            <h4 class="text-center">@item.Origin</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { pageNo = page }), PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I have taken Stephens comments onboard and now have a updated solution. This is nearly working put is giving a null `HomePageVM` object when passed back to the controller on the second page.

**Code:**

Updated HomePageVM model:

```
public class HomePageVM
{
    public List<string> GetCatagories { set; get; }

    public HomePageSearchVM SearchValues { set; get; }
}

public class HomePageSearchVM
{
    public string searchTerm { set; get; }
    public string searchCatagory { set; get; }
    public string countryCode { set; get; }
}
```

HomepageDisplayItems:

```
  public class HomepageDisplayItems
{
    public HomePageVM SearchProperties { set; get; }
    public PagedList<ViewDisplayItem> DisplayItems { set; get; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(HomePageVM homePageSearch, int pageNo = 1)
    { 
        RootObject response = _httpCaller.CallWebApiEndPoint(homePageSearch.SearchValues.searchTerm, homePageSearch.SearchValues.searchCatagory, homePageSearch.SearchValues.countryCode);

        List<ViewDisplayItem> viewModelResponseList = ConvertToViewModel(response);

        var displayObj = new HomepageDisplayItems()
        {
            SearchProperties = homePageSearch,
            DisplayItems = new PagedList<ViewDisplayItem>(viewModelResponseList, pageNo, 12)
        };

        return View(displayObj);
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

**NOTE: Setting homePageSearch to the model.SearchProperties object**

```
@using PagedList.Mvc

@model ShopComparisonEngine.Models.HomepageDisplayItems

......


@Html.PagedListPager(Model.DisplayItems, page => Url.Action("Index", new { homePageSearch = Model.SearchProperties, pageNo = page }), PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
```

Comment: You need to send the values as route parameters - `new { pageNo = page, someProperty = someValue, anotherProperty = anotherValue, etc }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for you reply. Do I need to pass in the filter variables with the model to my View that can then be set into the route parameters?

Comment: Yes, but its a bit hard to understand what you doing with your code (having 2 separate views and models and your use of `Ajax.BeginForm()`). Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734135/mvc-asp-sorting-items/33746073#33746073) for a typical example

Comment: @StephenMuecke Again thanks you for your time and reply. I have checked your answer and it has helped me progress but I'm still having a null issues when resending the HomePageVM object back to the Action method. Please see my EDIT in the original question.

Comment: `homePageSearch = Model.SearchProperties` wont work (have a look at the `href` attribute that your generating to understand). I still don't think you using the best approach, but you could make it work using `new { searchTerm = Model.SearchProperties.searchTerm, searchCatagory = Model.SearchProperties.searchTerm, .... }` and changing the method to `public ActionResult Index(HomePageSearchVM homePageSearch, int pageNo = 1)` but I'm totally confused because your view has `@model HomepageDisplayItems` and you have not shown that model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have added HomepageDisplayItems. Thanks for your advice again

Comment: @StephenMuecke I managed to sort this solution in the end by simplifying my VM and using you suggested method of passing the assigned variables through seperatly which then mapped to the model on my controller. If you can make this your answer i'll set it as correct.

Comment: No point repeating the code - have marked it as a dupe.