# Struggling to Customise PagedList.Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Project that uses PagedList.MVC.

I have a Screen on which that I want to enable the users to be able to retrieve a filtered data set (Filtered by Start Date, End Date and Location).

Right now my thinking is to add in some jquery on DocumentReady, and use that to replace placeholders in the URL for each page.

So right now I have the following code:

```
 PagedListRenderOptions pagerOptions = new PagedListRenderOptions()
{      
  FunctionToTransformEachPageLink = (liTag, aTag) => { aTag.Attributes.Add("class","foo"); liTag.InnerHtml = aTag.ToString(); return liTag;},
  DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation=true      
};
```

and

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, 
page => Url.Action(ViewBag.Method, new { page, AllOptions = PagedDealershipLocation, StartDate = "stPageDate", EndDate = "endPageDate" }), 
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(pagerOptions, ajaxopts)
```

Yet when the Paged List is rendered, the class has not been added to the html, so I can't use it to manipulate the url.

I appreciate that my current approach is already flawed, as if the filter is changed, this happens outside the DocumentReady function. But right now I just want to understand why using the code above, I am not seeing the class attribute to the `<a>` tags. (Ideally I'd prefer to be able to hook into the `<a>` tag being clicked, so I can always get the current filters, but that's the next issue once I can actually find the page anchors being generated!)

Comment: What makes you think you should be changing the url? The normal approach is to have a form (with `FormMethod.Get`) in the view containing the controls for filtering and then you submit the form, filter the data based on the form controls and return the view.

Comment: The way the app is currently structured, the filter controls are a partial containing a form that can be used on any page. 
The Pager is in a seperate partial at the foot of each page, and builds a series of A tags. As this is not in the form, I need a mechanism to send the form values back in the urls generated by the pager.

Comment: Which you do by using a form and posting to the GET method.

Comment: The pager is not in the form, and appears at the bottom of the page, whereas the filter is at the top (where the client wants it.) So are you suggesting I wrap the paged contents, and the pager inside the form?
Being as the pager doesnt submit the form, just creates a series of Page links, I don't see as to how this will help pass the form values back. (Though I am goign to power up the dev workstation and try this, as I suspect I am missing the obvious :-)

Comment: The pager is not supposed to be in the form. Give me a moment and I will give you a link to a another answer showing how to do it.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734135/mvc-asp-sorting-items/33746073#33746073) for a typical implementation

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look look at that, and figure out what I was missing before I led myself up the javascript path !

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, that did the trick. I was overcomplicating things!

Answer (score 1):

The trick was to ditch the javascript, and place the values needed from the filter back into the view via the ViewBag.

i.e.

```
  ViewBag.StartDate = StartDate;
  ViewBag.EndDate = EndDate;
```

Than, as my pager is in a partial, I also had to pass the data from the Viewbag to the partial;

```
  @Html.Partial("_Pager", @Model, new ViewDataDictionary {{ "Method", ViewBag.MethodName }{ "StartDate", ViewBag.StartDate }, { "EndDate", ViewBag.EndDate } })
```

Then I could close the circle by adding StartDate and EndDate to the Pager.

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model,
    page => Url.Action(ViewBag.Method, new { page, 
                                             StartDate = ViewBag.StartDate, EndDate = ViewBag.EndDate}), 
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(pagerOptions, ajaxopts) 

)
```

Comment: This is not a suitable answer (the comments could be deleted) and will no doubt be removed soon, so I will mark it as a dupe unless you want to add a detailed answer

Comment: Edited my answer to include detail.