# Paging is not working in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am designing one page where I am displaying some details with paging. Page works fine except paging. When i click on second page nothing happens. All data cureently displayed will also go. Also when i hit on second page control wont go to my action method. This is my pager code.

```
  @Html.PagedListPager(Model.logDetails, page => Url.Action("Index",
                 new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, filterdateTime=ViewBag.filterdateTimepageSize, }))
                Page @(Model.logDetails.PageCount < Model.logDetails.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.logDetails.PageNumber) of @Model.logDetails.PageCount
```

This is my action method code.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int? clientId, DateTime? dateofAction,string typeofDocument,string employeeID,string citizenId,int? currentFilter,DateTime? filterdateTime,int? page)
        {
            DB_KYC3Entities db = new DB_KYC3Entities();
            ViewBag.docTypes = new SelectList(db.tm_doc_type, "doc_typeid", "doctype_name");
            if (clientId != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                clientId = currentFilter;
            }
            if(dateofAction!=null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dateofAction = filterdateTime;
            }
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = clientId;
            ViewBag.filterdateTime = dateofAction;
            int pageSize = 8;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            VerificationLogBAL obj = new VerificationLogBAL();
            int docType = obj.GetDocDetails(typeofDocument);
            List<logDetails> logDetails = obj.getlogDetails(clientId?? default(int), dateofAction?? DateTime.Now, docType, employeeID, citizenId);
            IPagedList<logDetails> pagedLog = logDetails.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
            logDetailsEnumeration model = new logDetailsEnumeration();
            ViewBag.checkData = logDetails.Count;
            model = new logDetailsEnumeration()
            {
                logDetails= pagedLog
            };
            return View("Index",model);
        }
```

This is my view code.

```
<div class="forms">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "VerificationLog", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="message"></div>

        <div class="loginUsernamePassword">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="dataTable tableHover">
                <tr>
                    <th width="8%" scope="col">Client ID</th>
                    <th width="20%" scope="col">
                        <div class="form-box form-box-default">
                            @Html.TextBox("clientId", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @id = "clientId", @placeholder = "Client ID", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 20 })

                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th width="10%" scope="col">Date Of Action</th>
                    <th width="20%" scope="col">
                        <div class="form-box form-box-default">
                            @Html.TextBox("dateofAction", ViewBag.filterdateTime as string, new { @id = "dateofAction", @placeholder = "Date Of Action", @class = "txtBox form-control calender validate[required]" })
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%" scope="col">Type Of Document</th>
                    <th width="17%" scope="col">
                        <div class="form-box form-box-default">
                            @*@Html.TextBox("typeofDocument", ViewBag.filterdateTime as string, new { @id = "typeofDocument", @placeholder = "Type Of Document", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 20 })*@
                            @Html.DropDownList("docTypes",null,new {@id = "typeofDocument", @placeholder = "Type Of Document", @class = "form-control"})
                                                </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th width="15%" scope="col">Employee ID</th>
                    <th width="17%" scope="col">
                        <div class="form-box form-box-default">
                            @Html.TextBox("employeeID", ViewBag.filterdateTime as string, new { @id = "employeeID", @placeholder = "Employee ID", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 20 })

                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%" scope="col">Citizen ID</th>
                    <th width="17%" scope="col">
                        <div class="form-box form-box-default">
                            @Html.TextBox("citizenId", ViewBag.filterdateTime as string, new { @id = "citizenId", @placeholder = "Citizen ID", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 20 })


                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th width="10%" scope="col" colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons search" />
                </tr>
            </table>

            </div>
            }

        </div>
  @if (Model != null && Model.logDetails.Count != 0)
        {
            <br />
            <h2>Verification Log</h2>
            <br />
            <div id="GridDetails">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="dataTable tableHover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Label</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                        <th>UpdatedOn</th>
                        <th>UpdatedBy</th>
                        <th>UpdatedStatus</th>
                        <th>RejectComment</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var group in Model.logDetails)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@group.contentLabel</td>
                            <td>@group.contentValue</td>
                            <td>@group.updatedOn</td>
                            <td>@group.updatedBy</td>
                            <td>@group.updatedStatus</td>
                            <td>@group.rejectComment</td>
                        </tr>

                    }
                </table>


   [HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DB_KYC3Entities db = new DB_KYC3Entities();
    ViewBag.docTypes = new SelectList(db.tm_doc_type, "doc_typeid", "doctype_name");
    return View();
}
```

When i click on second page control wont go to my index method also. Also i have 5 textboxes so do i need to preserve the all 5 text box values in viewbag? Can someone tell me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PagedListPager` makes a GET call, not a POST, so you need to remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute from the `Index()` method. Associated with that, you need to change the form to also make a GET

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "VerificationLog", FormMethod.Get))
```

And yes, you need to *preserve the all 5 text box values in viewbag* (or better using a view model) and add those values in the pagers `Url.Action()` in the same way your are adding `currentFilter` and `filterdateTime`

Comment: this works like charm. But i have one doubt. I have below method also. Because on page load i am binding dropdown with database values. So will it conflict? [httpget]    public ActionResult Index(){ }

Comment: You can only have one GET method with the same signature. You do not need your other index method and it should be deleted. But you need to stop all this awful use of `ViewBag` everywhere and use a view model so that you strong bind to it. And that model will include properties (say) `int SelectedDocument` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DocumentList` (as well as properties for `Client`, `DateofAction` etc

Comment: Thanks i will try to use models. May i have some usefull links where i can use more models than viewbags in Paging concept?

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734135/mvc-asp-sorting-items/33746073#33746073) for an example