# How to sort a Grid using Viewmodel not ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have my code working and sorting correctly but I am using ViewBag to do so. I would like to clean up my code and use ViewModel instead to sort my grid but I'm stumped in how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Model**

```
public partial class Asset
    {
        public int AssetKey { get; set; }
        public int ProductKey { get; set; }
        public string InventoryOwner { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
public class InventoryManagementController : Controller
    {
        private Orders db = new Orders();


        public ActionResult Index(int? AssetNum, string keyword, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, int? page)
        {

            ViewBag.OwnerSort = sortOrder == "owner_asce" ? "owner_desc" : "owner_asce";
            ViewBag.AssetSort = sortOrder == "asset_asce" ? "asset_desc" : "asset_asce";
            ViewBag.SerialSort = sortOrder == "serialnum_asce" ? "serialnum_desc" : "serialnum_asce";
            ViewBag.ProductSort = sortOrder == "product_asce" ? "product_desc" : "product_asce";

            ViewBag.Keyword = keyword;
            var records = from s in db.Assets select s;
            string AssetNums = AssetNum.ToString();
            if (keyword != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                keyword = currentFilter;
            }
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = keyword;

            switch (sortOrder)
            {

                case "asset_asce":
                    records = records.OrderBy(s => s.AssetKey);
                    break;

                case "asset_desc":
                    records = records.OrderByDescending(s => s.AssetKey);
                    break;

                case "serialnum_asce":
                    records = records.OrderBy(s => s.SerialNumber);
                    break;

                case "serialnum_desc":
                    records = records.OrderByDescending(s => s.SerialNumber);
                    break; 

                case "product_asce":
                    records = records.OrderBy(s => s.Product.ProductName);
                    break;

                case "product_desc":
                    records = records.OrderByDescending(s => s.Product.ProductName);
                    break;

                case "owner_asce":
                    records = records.OrderBy(s => s.InventoryOwner);
                    break;

                case "owner_desc":
                    records = records.OrderByDescending(s => s.InventoryOwner);
                    break;

            int pageSize = 25; //Number of Records
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            return View(records.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            //return View(assets.ToList());
        }
```

**View**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<OrderDB.Models.Asset>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inventory HomePage";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

    <title>Index</title>
    <br />
   <h2>Inventory</h2>

        <table class="table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Asset Tag", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.AssetSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Serial Number", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SerialSort, keyword = ViewBag.Keyword, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Product", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ProductSort, keyword = ViewBag.Keyword, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>     
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Inventory Owner", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.OwnerSort, keyword = ViewBag.Keyword, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink(item.AssetKey.ToString(), "Details", new { id = item.AssetKey })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InventoryOwner)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <br />
        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Comment: Just create a view model containing `IPagedList<Asset> Assets` and properties for the filters (`string OwnerSort` etc) - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734135/mvc-asp-sorting-items/33746073#33746073) for an example

Comment: Ok, I've done that with `public string OwnerSort { get; set; }
        public string AssetSort { get; set; }
        public string SerialSort { get; set; }
        public string ProductSort { get; set; }public IPagedList<Asset> AssetsList { get; set; }` And deleted all of my Viewbags and switch cases from my controller. I see the other question you provided, but I'm confused on how my headers (when clicked) will distinguish from ascending to descending without any of my switch cases or Viewbags that i deleted.

Comment: Its no different from what you doing now. Instead of `ViewBag.OwnerSort = sortOrder == "owner_asce" ? "owner_desc" : "owner_asce";` in the controller, it will be `model.OwnerSort = sortOrder == "owner_asce" ? "owner_desc" : "owner_asce";`, and in the view it will be `@Html.ActionLink("Inventory Owner", "Index", new { sortOrder = Model.OwnerSort, ....})` instead of `@Html.ActionLink("Inventory Owner", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.OwnerSort, .... })`

Comment: I have the controller correct portion correct I believe, but when I go to enter `Model.OwnerSort` I get an error that `IPagedList does not contain OwnerSort` when its clearly in my Viewmodel. Also where are you getting the "model" part from in the "model.OwnerSort" from in the snippet of code you provided? `Asset model = new Asset();`?

Comment: What have you named you view model? Assuming its `AssetVM` then in the controller - `AssetVM model = new AssetVM(); model.OwnerSort = xxx;` etc and finally `model.AssetsList = records.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)`. That error means that you not passing the view model to the view - just the original code you have.

Comment: But there appear to be other issues with your code (but not sure if you have just omitted some code for brevity - for example, I assume you have a form in the view that is associated with `keyword` for filtering?)

Comment: Ok, I didn't have `model.AssetList = records...` I have it currently and I'm doing `return View(model);` But I am still getting the same error in my view trying to do `Model.OwnerSort...` I don't know why its not seeing my OwnerSort in my ViewModel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130999/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-crich).

Comment: Yes I do, I omitted some code so I wont have a ton of unless code in my question. Also so my question will not be so long because I have a lot of code. I'm just trying to get the idea of how to fix my problem with as few lines of code in my question as possible